# Why this hql statement is like an inner join?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hql

Why this HQL statement is like an inner join?

```sql
select 
    user.id,
    user.allocationVersion,
    user.tx.statusId,
    user.userId,
    user.nameFirst,
    user.nameLast,
    user.email1,
    user.statusId,
    user.tx.name,
    user.note1,
    user.note2
from 
    module.bb.jpa.User as user 
where user.clientId = :clientId
     order by user.id DESC
```

The `TX` class which is referenced in the User class can be `null`. Why do I get a result as if I did an `inner join`? I just get `User`s with a `TX` but I want all of them.

Comment: we are expecting more explaination and output error :)

Comment: There is no error. A user can have a TX but if the user doesn't have one he doesn't appear in the result list. I would like all the users to appear since I am not explicitly doing an inner join on the TX table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have referenced `tx.name` in user. It should not work if you access it in Java but in HQL to get the value for this column Hibernate make implicit join. To get all values you should do it explicitly and include outer join option.

Answer (score 3):

The [HQL reference](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) talks about this in section 14.4:

> HQL supports two forms of association joining: *implicit* and *explicit.*
>
> The queries shown in the previous section all use the explicit form,
>   that is, where the join keyword is explicitly used in the from clause.
>   This is the recommended form.
>
> The implicit form does not use the join keyword. Instead, the
>   associations are "dereferenced" using dot-notation. implicit joins can
>   appear in any of the HQL clauses. **implicit join result in inner joins
>   in the resulting SQL statement.**
>
> ```
> from Cat as cat where cat.mate.name like '%s%'
> ```

[highlighting by me].

What your HQL is basically equivalent to is:

```sql
select 
    user.id,
    user.allocationVersion,
    user.tx.statusId,
    user.userId,
    user.nameFirst,
    user.nameLast,
    user.email1,
    user.statusId,
    user.tx.name,
    user.note1,
    user.note2
from 
    module.bb.jpa.User as user 
    join module.bb.jpa.Tx as tx -- This is an abbreviated inner join
where user.clientId = :clientId
     order by user.id DESC
```

To "correct" this behaviour you will have to explicitly specify a `left outer join` or `left join` for short.